# Explain pair function in C++

Tags: c++11, std-pair

I encountered this code

```
#define pii pair<int, int>
#define pip pair<int, pii>

...

vector< pip > graph;
graph[i] = pip( c, pii(u,v));
```

When I try

```
graph[i] = pair<c,pair<u,v>>;
```

I get an error message

```
error: 'c' cannot appear in a constant-expression 
error: 'i' cannot appear in a constant-expression
error: 'j' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

Why are these two expressions not equal?

Comment: What are `c`, `i`, `j`, `u` and `v`? From `pip(c, pii(u,v))` I can deduce that `c`, `u` and `v` probably are ints. What do you want to achieve substituting them into template parameters of `pair`? And why do you think that changing normal brackets to angle brackets does not change the meaning of expression?

Comment: Yes the variables are ints. I am trying to understand how `pip(c, pii(u,v))`, how it works, and thought it was the same if I substitute the brackets since because of the `#define`. Also tried with normal brackets.

Comment: "thought it was the same if I substitute the brackets since because of the #define" - macros have nothing to do with angle brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) is a *type*, not a function.

Aside from the syntax being incorrect, the reason you're getting this error is because you are trying to pass `c` (a run-time variable) into the template parameters, here:

```
graph[i] = pair<c,pair<u,v>>;
```

Presumably you want something like this instead:

```
graph[i] = pip(c, pii(u,v));
```

Which equates to:

```
graph[i] = pair<int, pair<int, int>>(c, pair<int, int>(u,v));
```